# How to split the words of a field into different columns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to split the words of a field into different columns.

For example I have this dataframe that contains the first name of some students (could be anything) and the cities where they live (we have an array with all of them), and their age. Some names might be missing. The structure is cities and names, nothing else in addition, but the names could be with more words.

```
data = {'Students': ['Boston Terry Emma', 'Tommy Julien Cambridge', 'London', 'Amsterdam', 'Anna Madrid       Pauline', 'Mozart    Cambridge', 'Gigi Tokyo Lily', 'Paris Diane Marie Dive'],
       'Age': [23, 20, 21, 30, 26, 27, 18, 22]}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Students', 'Age'])

print (df)
```

And it looks like this:

```
                    Students  Age
0          Boston Terry Emma   23
1     Tommy Julien Cambridge   20
2                     London   21
3                  Amsterdam   30
4  Anna Madrid       Pauline   26
5        Mozart    Cambridge   27
6            Gigi Tokyo Lily   18
7     Paris Diane Marie Dive   22
```

The lit of the cities is this one:

```
   cities = ['Boston', 'Cambridge', 'Bruxelles', 'New York', 'London', 'Amsterdam', 'Madrid', 'Tokyo', 'Paris']
```

Within the `'Students'` column, the field could have numerous spaces.

After the splitting is done, the dataframe should look like this:

```
      Cities             Names  Age
0     Boston        Terry Emma   23
1  Cambridge      Tommy Julien   20
2     London               NaN   21
3  Amsterdam               NaN   30
4     Madrid      Anna Pauline   26
5  Cambridge            Mozart   27
6      Tokyo         Gigi Lily   18
7      Paris  Diane Marie Dive   22
```

In this new dataframe, the `Students` column was split into `Cities` and `Names`, while the `Age` column was not affected.

I tried this:

```
for string in df['Students']:
    a, b = string.split(' ')
    if a in cities:
        df['Cities'] = a
        df['Names'] = b
    else:
        df['Cities'] = b
        df['Names'] = a
        
print(df)
```

But it does not work..

I am a beginner and I really appreciate if you could help me! Thank you!!!!

Comment: What to do if a last name is also a city name? Such cases are frequent in real life...

Comment: Yes, it is true, you have a really good point.. but I don't know.. maybe it should be needed a better structure from the site/ or from where the data is taken.. but I just needed to learn from this toy example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for first matched values from list to new column, then use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with remove whitespaces in custom function and last empty string convert to missing values:

```
pat = f'({"|".join(cities)})'
df['Cities'] = df['Students'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)
f = lambda x: ' '.join(y for y in x.split())
df['Names'] = df['Students'].str.replace(pat, '', regex=True).apply(f).replace('', np.nan)

df = df[['Cities','Names','Age']]
print (df)
      Cities             Names  Age
0     Boston        Terry Emma   23
1  Cambridge      Tommy Julien   20
2     London               NaN   21
3  Amsterdam               NaN   30
4     Madrid      Anna Pauline   26
5  Cambridge            Mozart   27
6      Tokyo         Gigi Lily   18
7      Paris  Diane Marie Dive   22
```

EDIT: Solution with word boundaries for not extract `AnnaMadrid` to `Madrid`:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in cities)

df['Cities'] = df['Students'].str.extract(f'({pat})', expand=False)
f = lambda x: ' '.join(y for y in x.split())
df['Names'] = df['Students'].str.replace(pat, '', regex=True).apply(f).replace('', np.nan)

df = df[['Cities','Names','Age']]
print (df)
      Cities               Names  Age
0     Boston          Terry Emma   23
1  Cambridge        Tommy Julien   20
2     London                 NaN   21
3  Amsterdam                 NaN   30
4        NaN  AnnaMadrid Pauline   26
5  Cambridge              Mozart   27
6      Tokyo           Gigi Lily   18
7      Paris    Diane Marie Dive   22
```

Comment: sorry for bothering you, I would just have a small question if possible. I was wondering if I have for example AnneMadrid Pauline, how can the code be modified in order to remain AnneMadrid Pauline as a whole name instead of splitting it into different columns?

Comment: @AndrewTulip - then use `pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in cities)` for words boundaries instead `pat = f'({"|".join(cities)})'`

Comment: I got this error: 
ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups

Comment: @AndrewTulip - testing.

Comment: @AndrewTulip - It is correct, but also is necessary change `.str.extract(f'({pat})', expand=False)`, added to answer.